# opencv dnn disable detecting coco dataset for some categories and enable for others

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am using the code in this repository https://github.com/salar-dev/python-object-detection-opencv but I want to disable detecting the coco dataset for some categories and enable it for others

I tryed to delete some of the ssd_mobilenet nodes but the program stopped

Comment: To remove classes you can just ignore the output:  for each detected object:.if class x or class y: remove the detection. For detecting other kind kf objects you will have to retrain the DNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the line with #

```
      if len(classIds) !=0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
           # if classId == 44:
              cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
              cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId-1], (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 20), 
                       cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
```

**44 is class index in coco.names**